# How can you feed fake thoughts to Detect Thoughts?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Say a monster/NPC/whatever seeks a defense against reading his mind, but doesn't want to tip off would-be mind readers with a Ring of Mind-Shielding or something similar that just shields his thoughts. Instead, he wants them to believe they have successfully read his thoughts but in fact have gained misinformation. How can he do that?

I'm looking for existing ways to do this, not just *making* it doable with homebrew or DM fiat.

Comment: Are you looking for RAW, story justifications, or homebrew items/skills/spells? Those will get you very different answers.

Comment: @SirTechSpec- RAW preferably, but I am open to homebrew solutions.

Comment: Detect thoughts reads surface thoughts initially. When you say "fake", do you consider "I thought about unicorns for 5 minutes" faking a thought or misleading the caster?

Comment: @PremierBromanov- I mean misleading the caster, for example someone who seems to be the party's ally but in fact is directing them toward a trap.

Answer (score 12):

The Soul of Deceit ability, gained from level 17 Mastermind Rogues in SCAG, allows the user to have his thoughts shielded and even to lie through telepathy. It also allows one to fool magic that would otherwise force the user to tell the truth.

Comment: Probably the most powerful ability of the archetype (which makes sense, it is level 17, the Wish level).

Comment: True, its deadly dangerous in political campaigns

Comment: This is literally the only possible answer lol.

Comment: Well, a GOOlock could potentially do it if he knew who was trying to read his mind. He could use Thought Shield to block his mind, then attempt to deceive  the target by sending lies through Awakened Mind telepathy. It requires more DM approval and also has a lesser chance of success (disadvantage, etc.).